# Java indexOf not working as expected on object list

Tags: java

I few days ago I started messing around with Javas, wanting to create a small tool for League of Legends. Now I encountered a very frustrating error.

indexOf stopped working, but I just can't figure out why. Every time I check the list "players" for the position of the entered name (l1v3 in this case) it just responds with -1. So item not found. Even though is shows up when printing the "players" list.

What did I do wrong? I'm new to coding so thanks for the help in advance!

This is the output I get:

```
Name: Abanke
Summoner ID: QvpMxe-XUEfD2WQujoDzHg9q4_co-7A1B6QC4W51qh8r1B0
[kus olan kumru, Abanke, Al Muqtadir, Lilipp, Solalicious, Young BuII, Nimecchii, imapz, FSL Nubels, Ulanbator Raimi]
Enemies[Young BuII, Nimecchii, imapz, FSL Nubels, Ulanbator Raimi]
-1
```

Code:

```
package leaguetimer;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import net.rithms.riot.api.ApiConfig;
import net.rithms.riot.api.RiotApi;
import net.rithms.riot.api.RiotApiException;
import net.rithms.riot.api.endpoints.summoner.dto.Summoner;
import net.rithms.riot.constant.Platform;
import net.rithms.riot.api.endpoints.spectator.dto.CurrentGameInfo;

public class LeagueTimer {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws net.rithms.riot.api.RiotApiException
     */
     public static void main(String[] args) throws RiotApiException {
         // TODO code application logic here
                ApiConfig config = new ApiConfig().setKey("RGAPI-9aa36868-192b-481b-b9c7-a04facf84ce1");
        RiotApi api = new RiotApi(config);

        Summoner summoner = api.getSummonerByName(Platform.EUW, "Abanke");
        System.out.println("Name: " + summoner.getName());
        System.out.println("Summoner ID: " + summoner.getId());

                CurrentGameInfo match = api.getActiveGameBySummoner(Platform.EUW, summoner.getId());


                List players = new ArrayList();
                players = match.getParticipants();          
                System.out.println(players);

                int check = players.indexOf(summoner.getName());

                if (check < 5) {
                    List subList = match.getParticipants().subList(5, 10);
                    System.out.println("Enemies" + subList);
                    System.out.println(check);
                }

                else {
                    List subList = match.getParticipants().subList(0, 4);
                    System.out.println("Enemies" + subList);

                }
       }          

 }
```

Comment: Java and JavaScript are completely different languages.

Comment: This is Java, not JavaScript.

Comment: What kind of list is `players`? Why are you using raw types? What does `getName()` return? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that this is Java. New to this so I appreciate all the input. I have trimmed to code a bit and updated the post.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that this is Java. New to this so I appreciate all the input. @shmosel I have trimmed to code a bit and updated the post. getName() just returns the summoner name entered in the line above. "Abanke" in this example. I'm using raw types, because I can't find anything online on how to deal with the output of the match.getParticipants(), which is defined as List<CurrentGameParticipant>.

Comment: "is defined as List<CurrentGameParticipant>" that's the problem right there. You have a list of objects, and you're asking it whether it contains a string "Abanke". It doesn't, it never will, it only contains objects of type `CurrentGameParticipant`. You could do: `List<String> playerNames = players.stream().map(CurrentGameParticipant::getSummonerName).collect(Collectors.toList());  int check = playerNames.indexOf(summoner.getName());`

Comment: Thank you so much! Your code worked. I had to tweak the `List players = new ArrayList();` part to `List<CurrentGameParticipant> players = match.getParticipants();`. This was so that it fits the original list type right?